# ZF 2 :Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\View\HelperPluginManager

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I run the app created with Zend Framework 2 i get this Error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::__construct() must implement interface
>   Interop\Container\ContainerInterface, none given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Service\AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php
>   on line 32 and defined in
>   C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\HelperPluginManager.php
>   on line 241

how can i resolved that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

See the repo:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/issues/43

It's a bug in constructor of HelperPluginManager